# sklearn train test split by year

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I have a dataset that goes from 2016 to 2020 with a 'Year' column. I would like to use 2016-2017 as train data and 2018-2020 as test data. Is there any easy method to perform this data split?

Comment: There is no need to use sklearn, just filter using pandas:
`df_train = df[df['year'].isin(2016,2017)]` and  `df_test = df[~df['year'].isin(2016,2017)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby function to group all the data in 2016 to 2017 as training data and group data from the year 2018-2020 as test data.
Alternatively you can use the following code as well

```
df_train = df[df['year'].isin(2016,2017)] and df_test = df[df['year'].isin(2018,2019,2020)]
```